# I am getting an error from angular in the console saying "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: b". How can I overcome this error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to angular/ionic and I am trying to use the tindercards2 ionic framework and this is how my module is being declared.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionic.contrib.ui.tinderCards2'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {})
  .directive('noScroll', function($document) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
        $document.on('touchmove', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      }
    }})
```

But when I push my code online I get this error:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: b

Followed by:

```
 at http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:13437:12
    at http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:17787:19
    at getService (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:17940:39)
    at injectionArgs (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:17964:58)
    at Object.invoke (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:17986:18)
    at runInvokeQueue (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:17887:35)
    at http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:17896:11
    at forEach (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:13690:20)
    at loadModules (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:17877:5)
    at createInjector (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:17799:19)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=Error%3A…2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2Fnightly%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17799%3A19)
```

And finally:

"Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

How can I rewrite my module to stop this error from occurring? Is the issue even with my module?

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the minify script.
When the script is minified `$stateProvider` will become `a`and angular doesn't know `a`.

So you have inject your provider in this way : `['provider', function(provider) {}]`

just add this :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionic.contrib.ui.tinderCards2'])
  .config(['$stateProvider',' $urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {}])
  .directive('noScroll', ['$document', function($document) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
        $document.on('touchmove', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      }
    }}])
```

Look here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector (part : The array notation)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the changes you made and why they may be the solution to this problem? I just want to understand more so I can learn from it. Thank you!

Comment: Edit done, i'll try to find the document on official angular doc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have Bundling enabled, angular cannot identify the function parameters as they are minified during runtime.

For example. You have a directive **`.directive('sample', function ($scope){ });`**
this will work perfectly fine when Bundling is disabled. But when it is enabled,the error is thrown.

for that just locally scope the parameters like this,

**`.directive('sample',['$scope', function ($scope){ }]);`**

This is a simple explanation. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sorry I am new to all this but how do you know I have bundling enabled? Would another solution be to disable bundling?

Comment: I checked your logs, and i can see its a bundling issue. So it will be enabled in your config file.
One way is to disable bundling. But then, it does not minify any of the JS files.Another way is to include the angular js files as new Bundle() instead of new ScriptBundle() , and you can seperate out the js files that has to be minified/unminified.

Comment: Oh ok thank you for the help!
Which file would be turning bundling on?
I check conf.php and its not in there. The only place I see it is  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

Comment: It should be there in your Web.config or Global.asax file(Do you have these files). Or it might be called from any of your views.